Play Framework Ebean Firebird
I have a project in Play 2.8.18 but now I want to update it to Play 3.x.
There is a new version of Ebean 8.xx but it looks like it doesn't support Firebird 2.5
I'm testing using the "play-samples-3.0.x" "play-java-ebean-example":
build.sbt:
"org.firebirdsql.jdbc" % "jaybird-jdk17" % "3.0.2"
application.conf:
db.default.driver= org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
db.default.url= "jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/TEST.BGC?encoding=ISO8859_1&defaultResultSetHoldable=True"
db.default.username="sysdba"
db.default.password="masterkey"

but I'm getting:
Unable to determine the appropriate ebean platform given database product name [firebird 2.56wi] and ebean platform providers [H2, ClickHouse, DB2, Hana, HSqlDb, MySql, MariaDb, NuoDB, Oracle, Postgres,Cockroach,Yugabyte, SqlAnywhere, Sqlite, SqlServer]. With ebean 13+ we now have separate platforms (ebean-postgres, ebean-mysql etc) and should use database specific platform dependency like ebean-postgres. Note that we can use ebean-platform-all to include all the platforms.
I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or Ebean doesn't support firebird anymore.
I tried adding this too:
"io.ebean" % "ebean-platform-all" % "15.3.1" %
I tried using firebird 5.0
